# How to hide a row of dynamic Ionic table in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an dynamic ionic table  and i have generated columns and rows dynamically as below:

```
<ion-grid > 
<ion-row class="header-row"> 
<ion-col >HID</ion-col>
<ion-col >Company</ion-col> 
<ion-col >Country</ion-col>
<ion-col >CPID</ion-col> </ion-row> 
<ion-row *ngFor = "let data1 of tablevaleany;let i=index" class="data-row">
<ion-col >{{data1[0]}}</ion-col>
<ion-col >{{data1[7]}}</ion-col> 
<ion-col >{{data1[8]}}</ion-col>
<ion-col >{{data1[1]}}</ion-col>
</ion-row> 
</ion-grid>
```

Now i want to have control of single cells of my table. I'm trying to hide a particular row of a table under certain condition but doesn’t know how to do it.

In Javascript code I would write it as below:

```
     `if (isDiplay) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }`
```

Please help me to resolve this issue in Ionic 5.

Comment: This can be done in different ways, depending on several factors. So: 1) are you able to edit `tablevaleany` on it's source, or it's from some external service that you don't have an access to? 2) Are you looking to use `isDisplay` (or anything similar) on already displayed cells, or on all elements of `tablevaleany`? 3) When/where are you planing to trigger the `isDisplay` check - on some click or at some other condition being met? Depending on the answers, you might consider sharing more code.

Comment: 1)Yes, I can edit the tablevaleany values on it's source. 2) I want to hide only some rows of already displayed table. 3)I am trying to filter the table values under certain conditions. So, when selecting the values in dropdown only some rows of the table should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[ngClass]` and pass a class you have set the display as none to it.  eg

```
.hideRow {
   display:none;
}
.showRow{
   display:unset
}
```

then check for isDisplay as so

```
<tr [class.hideRow]="isDisplay !== 1">
 // table row contents
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr [ngClass]="isDisplay === 0 ? 'hideRow' : 'showRow'">
 // table row contents
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr [ngClass]="{'hideRow' : isDisplay !== 1">
 // table row contents
</tr>
```

See the ngClass Docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)